# Installing VS2010 components with SP1 beta

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010, service-pack

I hope this is the place for this kind of question.

I have VS2010 ult with the Service Pack 1 beta installed.

I want to play with F# and I need to install it. The problem is that because I have the SP1 installed, the VS DVD can't install the F# compiler.

I click on add new feature, I click on F#, the installer says:

"A selected drive is not longer valid. Please review your installation path settings before continuing with setup."

Of course the path is correct and I can't change it anyway...

I think that problem is because I have the SP1. I had the same problem in the past with VS2008 + SP1.

What can I do? Uninstalling VS2010 is not an option, it take ages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Remove SP1 beta then. Otherwise, remove VS2010 and next time do a restore point before installing beta software.